# Why does mode_t use 4 byte?

Tags: c, permissions, filesystems

I've just read about mode_t that it basically stores the following information:

- 7 boolean values for the file type (S_IFREG, S_IFDIR, S_IFCHR, S_ISBLK, S_ISFIFO, S_ISLINK, S_ISSOCK)
- 3*3 = 9 boolean values for the access permissons (read, write and execute for owner, group and others)

So it needs 16 bit = 2 bytes. I guess you could even have one bit less for the file type, as it has to be either a regular file, a directory, a character or block device, a socket, a symbolic link, or a pipe. Or do other file types exist?

So I've just checked the size of mode_t with

```
printf("Size: %d byte\n", sizeof(mode_t));
```

It uses 4 byte. Why does it use 4 byte? Is there any additional information I didn't notice?

edit:
I've just found that mode_t is defined in ptypes.inc:

```
type mode_t = cuint32;
```

cuint32 is a 32 bits sized, unsigned integer and defined in ctypes.inc:

```
type cuint32 = LongWord;
```

Perhaps this helps for the answer.

Comment: what if more options/flags etc. need to be added in the future?

Comment: It could be that it's simply typedef'ed from an `int`, which is 32 bits in most architectures. Or it's made bigger so it can fit future flags.

Comment: Your **int** type _may_ be 4 bytes even if you store in it the number "255"...
The "building block" is the processor architecture and moreover you have some free space for any other flag they'll need. OMG I hate bitflags!!!

Comment: It is a compiler implementation detail.  But the normal backing storage for bitfields is an int.  Which is probably 32-bits on your machine.

Comment: So the only reason it is 4 bytes is that something might eventually change in the future?

Comment: @moose: No, the reason is that using a 16-bit value here would have no benefit at all. Data structures on x86 are 32-bit aligned, so wherever this 16-bit value would be stored (inside a `struct`, on the stack, on the heap, in a register), it would take up 32-bits anyway in most cases. However, 32-bit values might be processed more efficiently by the CPU, which is *much* more important than space these days.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Thanks for your answer. If you posted it as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: BTW, You haven't specified your target. On iOS and Mac OS X mode_t seems to be a short (16 bits)

Comment: There are two flaws with your question. First of all you need additional bits for suid, sgid, and sticky bit. Second you won't need 7 bits for the format part - here you only need 3 bits (for the formats you've listed). Third linux have more formats than that so you need another bit to handle additional formats. You end up with the same number of bits though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at what a "dumb" compiler would do when given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  uint16_t test1 = 0x1122;
  uint32_t test2 = 0x11223344;
  if (test1 & 0x0100)
    printf("yay1.\n");
  if (test2 & 0x00010000)
    printf("yay2.\n");
}
```

This seems like a likely use case for values of type `mode_t`, checking if a flag is set. Now we compile it with `gcc -O0` and check the generated assembly:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
            ...
   f:   66 c7 45 fe 22 11       movw   $0x1122,-0x2(%rbp)
  15:   c7 45 f8 44 33 22 11    movl   $0x11223344,-0x8(%rbp)
  1c:   0f b7 45 fe             movzwl -0x2(%rbp),%eax  ; load test1 into %eax
  20:   25 00 01 00 00          and    $0x100,%eax
  25:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
            ...
  33:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax  ; load test2 into %eax
  36:   25 00 00 01 00          and    $0x10000,%eax
  3b:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
            ...
```

See how the special `movzwl` instruction is needed to load the 16-bit value? This is because it needs to be sign-extended to two additional bytes to fit in the register. Obviously this instruction is more complex than a simple `mov`. This might have a tiny impact on performance, and it might increase the executable size by some bytes, which by itself wouldn't be too bad.

However, if we consider that there would be no advantage in using a 16-bit value, because it would usually take up 32 bits of storage anyway due to alignment, it's clear why the designers choose to use the native word size of the CPU here.