# Is taking care of memory sizes bad in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, cpu

I'm wondering if taking care of memory sizes in C++ is a good or bad thing.
This question confused me ( [Why does mode_t use 4 byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602685/why-does-mode-t-use-4-byte) ).

So it's not performant to just use a char if I don't need to store a bigger amount of data, because a modern CPU has to fill up the rest?
So thinking of performance and saving computing time the best would be to always use a size_t for every integer typed variable I need?
Does a CPU still need more instructions to deal with a short value than dealing with an size_t if I have a large array?
What about char arrays? Wouldn't they be supposed to be slower, too?

All in all: What's the best practice? I'd like to save as much memory as possible, because my server does not have a lot of memory. On the other hand I don't want to loose performance because of me thinking memory is more important.

Is there somewhere a great explaination about how all this works and what's faster under what circumstances?

Comment: My hunch is that reading/writing/comparing the `char` will be as expensive as `size_t`, while mathematical operations will be more expensive. Why don't you write a test program?

Comment: I could just test this issue on a 32-bit machine, because to my knowledge I don't have access to a 64-bit machine currently.

Comment: What you shouldn't forget is locality. Handling smaller data may take more instructions, but if you have a large array, it means fewer cache misses. That can more than compensate the fewer instructions. Measure where it matters.

Comment: Relevant to your question are the new C++11 "fast" types. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). They will be at least the size you specify, but can be larger if the library developer feels that would be faster on a given architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one answer to this question.

1. Reducing the size of the integer types that you use can increase locality and decrease the required memory bandwidth.  So, that's a plus.  (Note: the actual memory fetch does not cost less.)
2. Increasing the size of integer types that you use can decrease the number of conversions required.  So, that's a plus.

So the questions are, how much memory do you save by choosing #1?  How many conversions do you save by choosing #2?

### The objective answer

In general, nothing less than whole-system profiling will tell you which is the better alternative.  This is because answering questions about reduced memory pressure is *incredibly* difficult and system-specific.  Reducing the memory usage of part of your program will typically *increase* the percentage of time your program spends in that part — and it may even increase the percentage of time that your program uses on the entire system — either due to the larger number of conversions necessary, or because the reduced memory pressure makes other parts of your system faster.  Hence the need for whole system profiling.

This, unsurprisingly, is a real pain.

### The subjective answer

However, my instinct tells me that it's almost never worth the effort to try and minimize memory usage of individual fields this way.  How many copies of `mode_t` do you think your program will have in memory at a time?  A handful, at most.  So I have a rule of thumb for this:

1. If it goes in an array, then use the smallest type that has sufficient range.  E.g., a string is `char[]` instead of `int[]`.
2. If it goes anywhere else, use `int` or larger.

So my subjective answer is, spend your precious time elsewhere.  Your time is valuable and you have better things to do than choose whether a field should be `int` or `short`.

Comment: The only time I reduce the size of field members is when, on embedded systems, there is no memory left.  Reducing field member size usually only effective for large quanitities.  We saved a lot of memory by reducing from 32-bit field members to 16-bit for over 32k records.  Reducing all those index variables won't have as big of an impact!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like premature optimization. You are worried about running out of memory when it seems like it hasn't actually happened yet.

In general, accessing a small subsection of the native word size of your CPU generates more CODE. So the space you save putting data into only 8-bits is probably lost 50+ times over by the added CODE needed to only manipulate the specific 8-bits you care about. You could also end up in places where your "optimization" slows things down, too:

```
struct foo {
    char a1, a2, a3;
    short b1;
};
```

If the above structure is packed tightly, b1 crosses a 32bit boundary which on some architectures will throw exceptions and on other architectures will require two fetches to retrieve the data.

OR not. It depends on the CPU architecture, the computer's data architecture, the compiler, and your program's typical use patterns. I doubt there is a single "best practice" that is correct 99% of the time here.

If space is really important, tell the compiler to optimize for size rather than speed and see if that helps. But unless you are sharing the data across a slow binary pipe, you should not generally care how big it is as long as it is big enough to hold all valid values for your application.

tl;dr? Just use size_t until you can prove that reducing the size of that specific variable will significantly improve server performance.

Comment: Optimizing for size doesn't change memory usage, it changes program code size.  (Well, that affects memory usage, but not very much.)

Comment: I know that. But if he really cares about memory usage, shrinking the code size can't hurt. IOW, he's already giving up speed for size, he may as well do it in the CODE too.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is processor dependent:  depends on the processor for the target platform.  Read its data sheet to find out how it handles single 8-bit fetches.

The ARM7TDMI processor likes to fetch 32bit quantities.  It is very efficient at that.  It is labelled as an 8/32 processor and can handle 8-bit quantities as well.

The processor may be able to fetch 8-bit quantities directly depending on how it is wired up.  Otherwise, it calculates the nearest 32-bit aligned address, reads 32 bits and discards the unused bits.  This takes processing time.

So the trade-off is memory versus processing time:

- Will compressing your application to use 8-bits significantly
  increase processing time?
- Does your development schedule gain any time by this task? (a.k.a. Return On Investment, ROI)
- Do your clients complain about the size of the application?
- Is your application correct and error free before worrying about
  memory usage?

Comment: Does discarding unused bits really take processing time? I'm not sure how ARM works but I have a hard time believing it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Arithmetic on a `short` that stays in a program register often requires extra instructions to discard the high bits.  For example, after adding two `short` values on PPC you'll have to `extsh` afterwards.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes it's true. CPUs only know how to do arithmetic with the whole register. To use a partial register, the compiler has to insert opcodes that do things like zero out the unused high bits and do things like sign extend the logical high bit (bit 15 of a short) through the unused bits so that the next arithmetic operation works.

Comment: @MarkRansom: it's an extra, probably unnoticeable, step that's not required when dealing with 32-bit quantities.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, C++ will do the usual arithmetic conversions so the operations themselves will use the full register. It's only the loading and saving of values that might require anything extra. And with today's processors I'd expect that overhead, if any, to be hidden by overlapping instruction execution.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The usual arithmetic conversions only allow C++ to use the full register for arithmetic operations.  However, the compiler will optimize out loads & stores to automatic variables, and place the automatic variables in registers rather than in memory.  For correctness, this will generate extra operations to trim the operand size *as if* they had been stored into memory.  These are the conversion operations I'm talking about.  Overlapping instruction execution will only get you so far, you can only overlap instructions where there is no data dependency.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I did a quick artificial benchmark on my PowerPC computer, since I know the PowerPC instruction set better.  The following loop takes 25% longer when using `short` instead of `int`.  https://gist.github.com/4439566

Comment: @MarkRansom: The overhead for loading/storing can be very noticable in the case where you work on arrays and do only a few operations on each data element. Loading a (unaligned, smaller) value into a register might need a load, a shift and a zero/sign extension. Storing it needs loading the data at the target address to a register, shift your register to the correct position, combine the two registers with an appropriate mask and write it back. That is lot of extra instructions, most of which are dependent on each other.